# Update field content with extension when saving or editing an entry

Tags: add-on-development, extension, hook

I have created an extension which uses the entry_submission_ready hook.
It is doing some calculations which I want to add to a field in the entry.

How can I add the output of the calculations to the field when saving an entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your values directly on the API object like so:

```
ee()->api_channel_entries->data['field_id_X'] = 'Foo';
```

Comment: Do you know if this will work when importing entries, does it use the same process as adding a new entry using the  hook?

Comment: I think so, but you'll have to experiment. Couldn't tell you without looking at the source.

Comment: I used datagrab and it worked perfectly